# Is Mata Parvati also devotee of Bhagwan Vishnu?

Tags: parvati

It is quite well known that Bhagwan Shiva is the biggest devotee of Shri Hari Vishnu.
And Bhagwan Vishnu is also biggest devotee of Bhagwan Shiva.
(Please correct me if I am wrong)

While Parvati is sister of Vishnu. Is she also devotee of Bhagwan Vishnu ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Parvati was a devotee of Lord Vishnu.

1.Lord Shiva says that Devi Parvati is a great devotee of Lord Rama -

> Lord Shiva said, 'Oh Goddess! **You are the blessed one. You are a
> great devotee of the supreme, absolute Lord** that you wish to know
> about the essential or elementary truth about the true nature of **Sri
> Ram.**

- Canto 1, Bala Kanda, Adhyatma Ramayana.

2. Parvati's words -

> O lord, you have well described the excellent practices of (i.e.
> sacred to) Viṣṇu, and the nature of the highest lord Viṣṇu, which is
> the greater secret than a secret (i.e. the greatest secret). O you
> saluted by all gods, **I am fortunate; I am blessed. Due to your
> favour I (shall) worship the eternal lord of gods.**
>
> O revered one, O best brāhmaṇa, **by your grace I shall properly
> worship Viṣṇu. Please permit me.**
>
> Oh, matchless is the greatness of Rāma, the highest soul. Even (after
> hearing it) for hundreds of kalpas my ears would not be satisfied. I
> am fortunate: I am blessed. O sinless one, you have told me
> everything. ***May I have, through your grace, devotion for Rāma in
> every existence.***

- Chapter 254, Uttara Khanda, Padma Purana.